# How do I reset my phpmyadmin completely without being able to go into phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

I have messed up my phpmyadmin completely and no matter what i do for my MAMP, this happens:

[image]

So i need to reset this completely. I am using a MacOS.

Comment: If **setup** directory exists in your phpmyadmin root directory then try to **remove config.inc.php from root directory.** After that open : **<your-phpmyadmin-url>/setup** and you can reconfigure your phpmyadmin.